# Solving a differential equation related to quasihomogeneous polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have these equations: $$\frac{dx}{dt}=ax^3+by^2 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{dy}{dt}=x^2y$$
I need to somehow find an expression for $y(x)$, and I have been given a hint that I can use the fact that these correspond to "quasihomogeneous" polynomials. I understand that this means that the degree of the polynomials $P(x,y):=ax^3+by^2$ and $Q(x,y):=x^2y$ have some special relaltion.

Once checked this relation,  to obtain an expression is straightforward, but again I am not sure how to do this. Sorry for the vagueness of this explanation but I am confused and I can not find any references or examples.

If you have some other method to deal with the system I will be glad to learn them as well.

Thank you!

Comment: $dy/dx = (x^2y)/(ax^3+by^2)$ so that $ x^2ydx-(ax^3 + by^2)dy =0$. So this is in the form $Mdx + Ndy=0$. This is an exact equation if $a=-\frac{1}{3}$. In which case you can use the methods of exact equations. If not, you can try to find a multiplier $P = \exp( \int \frac{M_y - N_x}{N}dx)$ or $P= \exp(\int \frac{N_x - M_y}{M}dx)$.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you can't always solves equations for $y=y(x)$ or $x=x(y)$ explicitly so sometimes you have to make due with an implicit solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2 y}{ax^3+by^2}. \tag{1}$$
@DogeChan's comment tells you how I would typically solve such a differential equation (as an [exact equation](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/exact.aspx)). However, I present below the approach which I think your professor wanted you to use based on the context you provided. Let
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2 y}{ax^3+by^2}.$$
We call the ODE $y'(x)=f(x,y)$ *quasihomogeneous* if for all $\lambda$ and for some $\alpha,\beta\neq 0$ we have
$$f(\lambda^{\alpha}x,\lambda^{\beta} y)=\lambda^{\beta-\alpha}f(x,y).$$
Once you find such $\alpha$ and $\beta$, make the change of variables $y=x^{\beta/\alpha}z$ to get a separable ODE.

---

Alternatively, you can derive the change of variables by computing the degree of the rational function
$$f(x,y)=\frac{Q(x,y)}{P(x,y)}=\frac{x^2 y}{ax^3+by^2}.$$
in $x$ and $y$. The degree of $f$ in $x$ and $y$ (denote by $\deg_x f$ and $\deg_y f$ respectively) is [by convention](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641780/degree-of-rational-function) given by the maximum of the degrees of $Q$ and $P$ in $x$ and $y$ respectively, where $Q$ and $P$ have no common factors. The change of variable is then given by
$$y=x^{\deg_y f/\deg_x f} z.$$
So in your case $\deg_x f=\max\{\deg_x Q,\deg_x P\}=\max\{2,3\}=3$ and $\deg_y f=\max\{\deg_y Q,\deg_y P\}=\max\{1,2\}=2$, therefore the appropriate change of variable is $y=x^{3/2}z$.

For more information on this method, see e.g. [this answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18849) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1972678/323432).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have found the weights already, but I am struggling a bit on the change of variables part. I have replaced already $F(x,z)$ where $z$ is defined as you mentioned, but I am having trouble seeing it is separable. Could you please elaborate a little bit more in that part?

Comment: Sure! By the product rule, $y=x^{3/2}z$ implies that $y'=(3/2)x^{1/2}z+x^{3/2}z'$. Plugging this into the ODE and simplifying gives
$$z'=\frac{1}{x}\left[\frac{z}{a+bz}-\frac{3}{2}\right],$$
which is clearly separable.

Comment: In the expression for $y'$, shouldn't we have $z'$ in the second term?

Comment: That's right, in my original edit for the comment I forgot to add it (it was a typo). I just fixed it.

Comment: Sorry, I found another mistake: It should be
$$z'=\frac{1}{x}\left[\frac{z}{a+bz^2}-\frac{3z}{2}\right].$$

Comment: Finally got it. You also missed $x'$ in the expression for $y'$ :)

Comment: I didn't miss that. Here the differentiation is with respect to $x$, not $t$. You can then plug in the expression for $y'$ directly to equation $(1)$.

Comment: Strange, I differentiated with respect to $t$ but anyhow got your exact same expression for $z'$ ($dz/dx$). I suppose both are correct.

Comment: Indeed, your approach should work too. It's just that you use the chain rule at a later step than I do (I use it at the very beginning to get equation $(1)$).

Answer (score 2):

The hint of the term 'quasihomogeneous' suggests that one should at least investigate the substitution

$u=x^{3/2}$ so that the first equation becomes $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=au^2+by^2$.

Completing the change of variables gives

$$ \frac{du}{dt}=\frac{3a}{2}u^{7/3}+\frac{3b}{2}u^{1/3}y^2\text{ and }\frac{dy}{dt}=u^{4/3}y $$

Therefore

$$ \frac{du}{dy}=\frac{3a}{2}\cdot\frac{u}{y}+\frac{3b}{2}\cdot\frac{y}{u} $$

which is homogeneous.