# What is the highest power of a function called if it is negative?

Tags: polynomials, terminology, rational-functions

$$
\text{Given }  \{n, \thinspace N\} \in \mathbb{N}^+ \text{ and } N > n \\
\ \\
\begin{align}
p(x) &= \sum_{n}^N a_n{x^n} \\
\ \\    
r(x) &= \sum_{n}^N \frac{a_n}{x^n}
\end{align}
$$

The highest power $N$ of a polynomial $p(x)$ is called its "degree". What is the highest power $n$ of $r(x)$ called?

Answer (score 1):

First some definitions: A rational function is any function that can be put in the form $f(x)/g(x)$ for polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. The [degree of a rational function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641780/degree-of-rational-function) $f(x)/g(x)$, assuming that this fraction is in lowest terms (i.e. $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have no common polynomial factors), is the maximum of the degree of $f(x)$ and the degree of $g(x)$.

In your case, you have a function $r(x)$ where the most negative exponent is $x^{-N}$. As I will show below, this coincides with the definition of the degree of a rational function, i.e. the degree of $r(x)$, so the name for the most negative exponent in this case is just called the degree of the rational function.

To find the degree of the function $r(x)$ you made, we first need to put $r(x)$ into the form of one polynomial divided by another polynomial. To do this, we just need to factor out $1/x^N$ from the sum:
$$r(x)=\frac{\sum_{i=n}^N a_i x^{N-i}}{x^N}$$
Assuming $a_N\neq 0$, this fraction is in lowest terms because the only factors of the denominator polynomial are powers of $x$, while the numerator polynomial has a constant term of $a_N\neq 0$ and thus does not have $x$ as a factor.

The degree of the numerator polynomial, $\sum_{i=n}^N a_i x^{N-i}$, is at most $N-n$ since the highest-degree term, if $a_n\neq 0$, is $x^{N-n}$. The degree of the denominator polynomial, $x^N$, is just $N$. Thus, the degree of $r(x)$ is the maximum of $N-n$ and $N$, which is just $N$, which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: I've done some more digging. It seems there are multiple definitions for "degree of a rational function". This was where I was getting turned around with the terminology. I was looking for the definition used in asymptotic analysis (see [Rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function#Degree) Wiki).